# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type')

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

i want to print Alert in  react app but i can't able to print coz this.
when type {props.alert.type} as well as {props.alert.mag} the code not working .
so please help m get stuck in this code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Alert from './component/Alert';
import TextFrom from './component/TextFrom';


function App() {
  const[mode,setMode] = useState('light');//wheather dark mode is enabled or not
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

 const showAlert=((message,type)=>{
      setAlert( {
         msg:message,
         type:type
       }) 


const toggleMode=()=>{
    if(mode === 'light'){
      setMode('dark')
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='#14142c';
      showAlert("Dark modes enabled", "success");
    }
    else{
      setMode('light')
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='white';
      showAlert("light mode is enabled", "success");
    
  }
}

 return (
        <>      
        <Navbar title="TextUtils" mode={mode} toggleMode={toggleMode} /> 
        <Alert  alert={alert}/>
        <div className='container'>
        <TextFrom heading="Enter the text given below" mode={mode}/>
        </div>
          </>
     );
  }    
  

export default App;

// upper code is this for 'App' main page.
```

```
// bottom is another page //
import React from 'react'

function Alert(props) {
    return (
        <div>
          props.alert && <div className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show " role="alert">
                <strong>{props.alert.type}</strong>: {props.alert.msg}
                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Alert
```

so please help me to resole the code so i can  continue the work on the website .

this output is showing when m run this app given below the screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRGZo.png)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a syntax error in your Alert component, it's missing some curly braces.

Replace the following line in your Alert component:

```
props.alert && <div className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show " role="alert">
```

With the following line:

```
{props.alert && <div className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show " role="alert">
```

This should fix the issue and render the alert properly.

Comment: thanks dear now  website is working thank alot m get stuck last 3 day u solov me this issue . thanks alot